# Error when loading spaCy model trained from config file: ValueError: Cannot get dimension 'nO' for model 'sparse_linear': value unset

Tags: python, spacy

I'm encountering an issue with a spaCy model trained from a config file. I've successfully trained, evaluated, and saved the model. However, when attempting to load text into the nlp component for prediction, I encounter the following error:

Copy code

```
ValueError: Cannot get dimension 'nO' for model 'sparse_linear': value unset
```

```
nlp = spacy.blank("pl")

df_spacy = pd.DataFrame(df_to_model[['desc_transformed', 'final_label_grouped']])
df_spacy.reset_index(inplace=True)

class_names = ['anulacja', 'dostawa', 'other', 'reklamacja', 'zwrot']

categories = df_spacy['final_label_grouped'].values.reshape(-1, 1)

encoder = OneHotEncoder()
one_hot_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(categories)
one_hot_array = one_hot_encoded.toarray()

df_encoded = pd.DataFrame(one_hot_array, columns=class_names).astype(int)

label = list(df_encoded.columns)
df_encoded = df_encoded.to_dict('index')

dataset = list(zip(df_to_model['desc_transformed'], [{'categories':cat} for cat in df_encoded.values()]))

train_data, test_data = train_test_split(dataset,
                                        test_size=0.25,
                                        random_state=42)
dev_data, test_data = train_test_split(test_data, 
                                       test_size=0.4,
                                       random_state=42)

print(f"Total: {len(dataset)} - Train:  {len(train_data)} - Dev: {len(dev_data)} - Test: {len(test_data)}")

def convert(data, outfile):
    db = spacy.tokens.DocBin()

    for text, labels in data:
        doc = spacy.tokens.Doc(nlp.vocab, words=text.split())
        doc.cats.update(labels['categories'])
        db.add(doc)

    db.to_disk(outfile)

convert(train_data, "./train.spacy")
convert(dev_data, "./dev.spacy")
convert(test_data, "./test.spacy")

textcat = nlp.add_pipe("textcat_multilabel")
for i in label:
    textcat.add_label(i)

! python -m spacy init fill-config base_config.cfg config.cfg

! python -m spacy train config.cfg --output ./output --paths.train ./train.spacy --paths.dev ./dev.spacy

! python -m spacy evaluate ./model/model-best/ ./test.spacy

def predict_spaCy(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    

    label = max(doc.cats, key=doc.cats.get)
    
    return label

text_to_classify = "klient pytanie produkt ASIN   połączenie dachówka wentylacyjny   link zapytanie web_site pozdrawiać persName"
predicted_label = predict_spaCy(text_to_classify)

print("Predicted Label:", predicted_label)
```

I've searched extensively for a solution but haven't found one. Could anyone provide insight into what might be causing this error and how it can be resolved?

I've thoroughly searched Stack Overflow, consulted with ChatGPT, reviewed the spaCy documentation, and searched extensively on Google to find any hints on how to handle this error, but haven't found a solution. Could anyone provide insight into what might be causing this error and how it can be resolved?